# How to resolve a type with Autofac that requires an instance that has that an instance of the type as ctor parameter

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac

Currently I solve the problem with a delegate in this way:

```
builder.Register(componentContext =>
                 {
                     var logger = componentContext.Resolve<ILogger>();
                     var logger1 = logger.ForContext(typeof(MainWindow));
                     var view = new MainWindow(logger1);

                     var logger2 = logger.ForContext(typeof(MainWindowModel));
                     var model = new MainWindowModel(logger2, view);

                     view.DataContext = model;

                     return view;
                 });
```

Is there a more elegant way to solve the problem?

EDIT:

The problem is not how to resolve ILogger.  The problem is, that I have the `MainWindowModel` class that requires the same `MainWindow` instance I created in the first step (the instance that get passed in `logger1`) as a constructor parameter.  If I would leave the instantiation of `view` to Autofac, I would have one instance resolved for `MainWindow` and an instance of `MainWindowModel` with a different instance of `view` passed in as constructor parameter (which would be wrong, as I need the same instance of `MainWindow` passed into `MainWindowModel`.

I hope that clarifies my question a bit more.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] to provide all the necessary classes ready to use. Have you tried conditional registration like `OnlyIf()` or `WithParameter()`? What have you tried and what were the problems you had?

Comment: @Progman: Well, I thought my sample clearly enough explains what I am currently doing and my question still is: Is there a better way of doing it?  Maybe you can explain more in detail why you are mentioning `OnlyIf()` or `WithParameter()`.  I assume that you believe that these methods might help to get a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you describe is injecting services based on the type of the component being activated. The Autofac documentation contains [a great log4net example](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/log4net.html) on how you can use [pipeline middleware](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/pipelines.html) to inject parameters based on the component type.

Based on the example, your middleware would look something like this:

```
public class LoggerMiddleware : IResolveMiddleware
{
    public PipelinePhase Phase => PipelinePhase.ParameterSelection;

    public void Execute(ResolveRequestContext context, Action<ResolveRequestContext> next)
    {
        context.ChangeParameters(context.Parameters.Union(
            new[]
            {
              new ResolvedParameter(
                  (p, i) => p.ParameterType == typeof(ILogger),
                  (p, i) => {
                                var logger = context.Resolve<ILogger>();
                                return logger.ForContext(p.Member.DeclaringType);
                            }
              ),
            }));

        next(context);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is you want?

Register

```cs
builder.RegisterType<MainWindow>()
       .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
builder.RegisterType<MainWindowModel>()
       .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

Model

```cs
 public class MainWindowModel
    {
        private readonly ILogger<MainWindowModel> _logger;
        private MainWindow _mainWindow;
        public MainWindowModel(ILogger<MainWindowModel> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public void SetMainWindow(MainWindow mainWindow)
        {
            _mainWindow = mainWindow;
        }
    }

    public class MainWindow
    {
        private readonly ILogger<MainWindowModel> _logger;

        public MainWindow(ILogger<MainWindowModel> logger, MainWindowModel dataContext)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            this.DataContext = dataContext;
            this.DataContext.SetMainWindow(this);
        }

        public MainWindowModel DataContext { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the whole equation. How is `ILogger<T>` registered? Without it, Autofac will not be able to provide the service to the other types.

Comment: what is your .net version, because `ILogger<T>` will auto resolve, if not you can try `builder.RegisterInstance(new LoggerFactory()).As<ILoggerFactory>()`
`builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(Logger<>)).As(typeof(ILogger<>)).SingleInstance()`

Comment: my point is that you don't show _how_ `ILogger` is registered with the container. Neither does the OP :) Based on the OPs example, we can assume that `ILogger` can be resolved, but we do not know that the logging framework being used actually supports resolving `ILogger<T>`.